# csv reading the old way

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm fully aware how to read csv files with Python the normal way. I'm also aware that I can parse lists (e.g. `["a, b, 123"]`). Both work because of generators and yield.

My problem is slightly different:

- Input is a `dict` like `{"line": "a, b, 123", "line_count": 555, ..}`
- Output should be the same `dict` extended with a `"csv"` attribute like
   `{"line": "a, b, 123", "line_count": 555, .., "csv": ["a", "b", "c"]}`

The easiest and very traditional approach would be (pseudo code):

```
def my_csv_reader(myconfig):
    my_reader = CsvReader(**myconfig)
    for line in some_gen_providing_the_list_of_dicts:
        line["csv"] = csv.reader(line["line"])  (1)
        yield line
```

I'm actually able to use this approach by replacing line marked (1) with:

```
line["csv"] = csv.reader([line["line"]], **myconfig)  (1)
```

But I need to parse 500 mio lines, and creating and initializing the CSV object for every single line likely creates lots of garbage and in fact is unnecessary. I also don't like that header lines, `DictReader`, etc. will no longer be built-in. If I only would be able to:

- Create a csv `reader` object.
- Invoke a boring old-fashioned `to_csv(my_line)` function returning the csv for that line.

Is that somehow possible with Python 3.x?

Comment: No, the traditional way is to make a CSV reader out of an iterable of rows, like a file object, not to make a separate reader for each line.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
def to_csv(s):
  s = s.split(',')
  s = [t.strip() for t in s]
  return s

def csv_reader(dicts):
  for d in dicts:
    d['csv'] = to_csv(d['line'])
    yield d
```

Comment: where in your solution is support for headers, DictReader, dialects, etc.?